# Bending original wireframe around subdivision simulation

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I am using subdivision modifiers heavily, but often come into a situation where it is hard to select one specific vertex or edge of the edited mesh, because the vertex sits at the bottom of a cavity which gets leveled by the subdivision modifier. With X-Ray *enabled*, there are so many edges visible, that it is hard to visually identify the right one among all the others, while with X-Ray *disabled*, the wanted edges are visually hidden *behind* the faces simulated by the subdivision modifier. On the other hand, disabling and enabling the subdivision modifier on-the-fly is rather annoying, as what I actually want to see while editing is how my current mesh-editing step actually modifies *the simulated* outcome.

From other modelling software I learned that they do have a feature that I think would be very beneficial for me here: A mode that makes the original wireframe "bend" accordingly to the simulated wireframe's geometry. "Bending" here means that the edges of the edited mesh are not shown as *straight* lines but as *curves*, and vertexes are shown relocated ontop of the simulated surface. Due to that, lines and vertexes *always* are visible (hence selectable) as they always lie *outside* of the subdivided simulation.

Is there such a mode in Blender 3.4.1 and how can I enable it?

Comment: Does enabling the On Cage icon at the top of the modifier panel help (L/H triangular icon)?

Comment: Thank you, @JohnEason! This button was exactly what I needed! I really appreciate your kind and quick help! :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for adding it as an answer. I've added an image showing its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a mode in Blender 3.4.1:

- Right to the name of the subdivision modifier in its properties, click on the icon that shows a triangle ("On Cage").

[image]

*Thank you, John Eason, for suggesting this solution!*